# Input value doesn't change on setState

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting a response from an API and want to change input values when the response is ready, currently, inputs are not changing values.

This is where I get and set the values I want in the input fields:

```
handleCepChange = data => {
    let aux = {
            "cidade": data.localidade,
            "rua": data.logradouro,
            "bairro": data.bairro,
        }
    this.setState({endereco: aux})
}

handleCep =  event  => {
    const handleCepChange = this.handleCepChange;
    const e = event.target.value;
    var cep = e.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (cep != ""){
        var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
        if(validacep.test(cep)) {
            const api = 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/'+ cep + '/json/';
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    handleCepChange(data);
                }
            }
            request.open("GET", decodeURI(api), true)
            request.send(null)
        } else {
            console.log("cep Invalido")
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I save my html on the state, so that I can render later:

```
new_item(isEdit) {
        let div = [];
        let new_item = {};
        if(!isEdit){
            new_item = {
                'descricao': '',
            };
        }
        else{
            new_item = {
                'descricao': isEdit.descricao,
            };
        }
        let fields =
            <div className='containerFields'> 
                <div className='wrapperFields'>
                    <label>  
                        <span class='fieldTitle'>Cep</span> 
                        <InputMask onBlur={this.handleCep} type="text" mask="99.999.999"></InputMask>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span class='fieldTitle'>Cidade</span> 
                        <input onBlur={(e) => new_item.descricao = e.target.value} value={this.state.endereco['cidade']} class='inputTextCriar' type='text'></input>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span class='fieldTitle'>Bairro</span> 
                        <input onBlur={(e) => new_item.descricao = e.target.value} value={this.state.endereco['bairro']} class='inputTextCriar' type='text'></input>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span class='fieldTitle'>Rua</span> 
                        <input onBlur={(e) => new_item.descricao = e.target.value} value={this.state.endereco['rua']}  class='inputTextCriar' type='text'></input>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                </div>
            </div>
    div.push(fields)
    this.setState({header : div});
```

And then finally, comes my render():

```
render() {
   {this.state.header}
}
```

I do have another header that's not relevant here, if trigger my handleCep(), leave this header and come back to it again, then I'll get my changes. but that's how I want it to work, I'd like to see the changes as soon as state changes. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

hi i guess what you missing is binding so change your code like below and give it a shut:

```
handleCep =  event  => {
    cosnt context = this;//--------here
    const e = event.target.value;
    var cep = e.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (cep != ""){
        var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
        if(validacep.test(cep)) {
            const api = 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/'+ cep + '/json/';
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    context.handleCepChange.bind(context,data);//-------------here
                }
            }
            request.open("GET", decodeURI(api), true)
            request.send(null)
        } else {
            console.log("cep Invalido")
        }
    }
}
```

2- i suggest that using component for header instead of saving it in state

Comment: didn't work, I don't think that's the problem, because I'm getting handleCepChanges() calls when I should, and state is changing. It's just that input fields are not updating

Comment: isn't it better to use component instead of saving html it in state variable

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to call `new_item` when the new states are set from your XHR since this is where you set the state for the new HTML for the header

```
handleCepChange = data => {
    let aux = {
        "cidade": data.localidade,
        "rua": data.logradouro,
        "bairro": data.bairro,
    }
    this.setState({ endereco: aux }, ()=>{
        new_item(someParameter)
    })
}
```